# Resources$NotFoundException. layout with resource id x7804000c is not present in the apk , Android -23, Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-resources, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
08-13 16:29:27.288 10821-10821/com.a.b.c E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.a.b.c, PID: 10821
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7804000c
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
    at android.view.ViewStub.inflate(ViewStub.java:259)
```

I am using android-dfm, and one of module is not laoding in Android-23, throwing above error.
**I tried searching for this res id(0x7804000c) through apk analyzer but could not find any layout with this resource id**. This error is occurring in both release as well as debug(without obfuscation).

Answer (score 0):

0x7804000c - Resource ID - it's some generate ID for resource. It's generate on Build for every resources in R.*

you can see in R file what resources is 0x7804000c